# What's the difference between `=` and `<-` in R?

Tags: r, assignment-operator, variable-assignment

I'm using R 2.8.1 and it is possible to use both `=` and `<-` as variable assignment operators. What's the difference between them? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html):

> The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are evaluated. The operator <- can be used anywhere, whereas the operator = is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions.

Comment: As `<-` can be used anywhere, does this mean that there is no need to use `=` ?

Comment: No, you need to still need to use `=` when calling functions to avoid assigning globally. Look at these examples: http://www.mayin.org/ajayshah/KB/R/html/b1.html. If you used `name<-"paypal", x<-2, ...` it would set `x` at the top level. Try running that example but writing `<-` instead of `=` and see what happens.

Comment: The documentation is (still to this day) wrong. `=` is *not* only allowed on the top level. Except for operator precedence, the `<-` and `=` assignment operators are completely identical by default. R complicates matters by giving `=` a *secondary* syntactic meaning, besides its use as an assignment operator.

Answer (score 19):

Reading from "Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R", by Robert and Casella:

"The assignment operator is `=`, not to be confused with `==`, which is the Boolean operator for equality. An older assignment operator is `<-` and, for compatibility reasons, it still remains functional, but it should be ignored to ensure cleaner programming. 
(As pointed out by Spector, P. (2009). 'Data Manipulation with R' - Section 8.7., an exception is when using `system.time`, since = is then used to identify keywords)

A misleading feature of the assignment operator <- is found in Boolean
expressions such as

```
> if (x[1]<-2) ...
```

which is supposed to test whether or not x[1] is less than -2 but ends
up allocating 2 to x[1], erasing its current value! Note also that using

```
> if (x[1]=-2) ...
```

mistakenly instead of (x[1]==-2) has the same consequence."

Comment: I also think that `global assignment`, whatever the need for doing something like this, can only be performed using the ("gets"-based) `<<-` operator, and that there is not an "equals"-based equivalent.

Comment: Google's R style guide says the opposite: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#assignment

Comment: `if (x[1]=-2)` is conveniently prohibited to prevent this kind of error. Specifically, the operator `=` is only allowed at the top level.

Comment: He asked what the difference was. This is a non-answer.

Comment: Reading the official R documentation, I'm not sure this statement is true:  *An older assignment operator is <- and, for compatibility reasons, it still remains functional,*