# Are `=` and `<-` exactly the same in R?

Tags: r, assignment-operator

Is it just a style preference?

As far as I can tell, they are the [same](http://developer.r-project.org/equalAssign.html).

I see many people prefer the "longer" `<-` version and I can't tell why (perhaps keeping away from `=` and `==` confusions?)

Comment: See [
Assignment operators in R: ‘=’ and ‘<-’
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and).

Comment: Can someone tag that older post with `assignment-operator`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271575/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-r-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not exactly the same: the `=` operator cannot be used everywhere that `<-` can.

> The operators <- and = assign into the environment in which they are evaluated. The operator <- can be used anywhere, whereas the operator = is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions.

There are also differences in scope. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and/1742550#1742550) for more details.

Which is better depends on who you ask.

---

Reading from "Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R", by Robert and Casella:

> "The assignment operator is =, not to be confused with ==, which is the Boolean operator for equality. An older assignment operator is <- and, for compatibility reasons, it still remains functional, but it should be ignored to ensure cleaner programming. (As pointed out by Spector, P. (2009). 'Data Manipulation with R' - Section 8.7., an exception is when using system.time, since = is then used to identify keywords)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271575/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-r-language/2271905#2271905)

---

On the other hand, [Google's R style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html#assignment) recommends using `<-`:

> ### Assignment
>
> Use <-, not =, for assignment.
>
> **GOOD**:
> x <- 5
>
> **BAD**:
> x = 5

Comment: That's a bizarre statement from P. Spector, no? I feel like the prevailing "idiomatic" style is still to use "<-" for assignment and "=" for arg lists, esp. from r-help and bioc mailing lists, no?