# Bug in R with subset

Tags: r

I have some trouble while trying to get a subset of an initial dataframe as in the end it corrupts my dataframe! Here is an example of what is happening:

Let consider a dataframe :

```
>test=data.frame("v1"=c(1,2,3,4,-5,-3),"v2"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
> print(test)
  v1 v2
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  4  4
5 -5  5
6 -3  6
```

Then I want to take the subset where var1 value is strictly below, let's say -2:

```
> subtest=test[test$v1<-2,]
> print(subtest)
  v1 v2
2  2  2
> print(test)
  v1 v2
1  2  1
2  2  2
3  2  3
4  2  4
5  2  5
6  2  6
```

Not only did the subset operation didn't work but it actually corrupt my initial database by replacing all the v1 values by 2 !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2271905/967840

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I t is not a bug. It is just a typo!

The operator `<-` is used to assign values. In the command `subtest=test[test$v1<-2,]`, you have assigned all values of variable `v1` to `2`.

To do what you want, you should do that instead:

```
subtest=test[test$v1< -2,]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug. You just have to put brackets, because otherwise it will be assignment mark `<-`. If you want strictly below -2:

```
subtest=test[test$v1<(-2),]
```

Comment: a space would be more conventional: `test$v1 < -2`