# If statements with variables in the form of words in r

Tags: r

This is an incredibly simple question. If I have a variable defined by a word such as:

```
variable1 = 'returns'
```

This would be something that I could later edit (i.e. change 'returns' to 'revenue').

I then want to execute a particular block of code provided that the variable is 'returns'. Why does R tell me that I cannot use an = sign when I try:

```
if(variable1 = 'returns'){
#code would go here
}
```

Comment: It should be `==`.  The `=` is another way to assign and not compare

Comment: `if (variable1 == 'returns') ...`  You need to use `==` for equality

Comment: @akrun Bonus points if you can explain what value an assignment itself would return.

Comment: perfect, thank you both!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not sure I understand your comment. To the OP, the `if/else is a conditional statement, so you need to have a logical element that returns from variable == 'returns'

Comment: also, since I'm already asking embarrassing questions, is there any difference between = and <- other than clarity for how something is assigned?

Comment: @akrun In most programming languages, probably in R as well, an assignment itself returns a value.  This could have given the OP false signals that `=` is "working."

Comment: @alex1stef2    Take a look at [Difference between assignment operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2271575/4752675)